# Span of a union and the intersection of sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three statements that I want to prove or find a counterexample.
Assume that $V$ is a vector space, for all subsets $S\subset V$ and $T\subset V$ we have;
$$\begin{align}
(1)\qquad \text{span}(S\cup T)&=\text{span}(S)+\text{span}(T)\\
(2)\qquad \text{span}(S\cap T)&=\text{span}(S)\,\cap\,\text{span}(T) \\
(3)\qquad \text{span}(S+T)&=\text{span}(S)+\text{span}(T)
\end{align}
$$
I think they are all correct, but I am having a hard time proving (2) and (3) and understanding the difference between $S\cup T$ and $S+T$. This is what I have so far;

(1) Let $S=\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ and let $T=\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$. The set $S\cup T$ contains all vectors in $S$ and all vectors in $T$. Thus a vector $w$ in $\text{span}(S\cup T)$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
    w=a_1u_1+b_1v_1+\dots+a_nu_n+b_mv_m=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i +\sum_{j=1}^m b_jv_j
\end{align*}
but any vector $u$ in $\text{span}(S)$ can be written in the form of the first sum and any vector $v$ in $\text{span}(T)$ can be written in the form of the second sum, therefore the statement is true.

(2) Let $S=\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ and let $T=\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$. The subset $S\cap T$ is the set of all vectors shared by both subsets. Therefore a vector $w\in \text{span}(S\cap T)$ can be written as
$$\begin{equation}
w=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iu_i=\sum_{j=1}^m b_jv_j
\end{equation}$$
In my head, if you start with the other side and try to express $\text{span}(S)\cap\text{span}(T)$ you would get the exact same thing, but I don't understand how to formulate it.

(3) For this one I don't really get what the difference between $S+T$ and $S\cup T$ is.

Comment: $\operatorname{span}(S\cap T)=\operatorname{span}S\cap\operatorname{span}T$ is just false. In linear algebra there isn't a standard, if at all, definition of $S+T$ when $S$ and $T$ aren't vector subspaces. The somewhat obvious one of $S+T=\{y\in V\,:\, \exists s\in S,\exists t\in T, y=s+t\}$ does not make the identity $\operatorname{span}(S+T)=\operatorname{span}S+\operatorname{span}T$ true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof of (1) is fine.

A counterexample to both (2) and (3) is $S=\{u\},T=\{-u\},$ for some $u\ne0$ in an $\Bbb R$-vector space.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how this disproves (2) and (3). However, I am still a bit unsure about the definition of S+T in the more general case. If $S=\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ and $T=\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ then how is the set $S+T$ defined?

Comment: See @SassatelliGiulio's comment above, or [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition). $S+T=\{u_i+v_j\mid 1\le i\le n,1\le j\le m\}.$